Ambiguous overloaded operator== in C++20 and g++ 13 when using CRTP
I'm migrating a codebase to C++20 and I end up having an issue with this pattern:
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type>
struct PartialEq {
    friend bool operator==(PartialEq const&, Type const&) {
        return true;
    }
};

struct A : PartialEq<A> {
};

int main()
{
    A a1{}, a2{};
    std::cout << (a1 == a2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Godbolt link is here
g++ is complaining about an ambiguous operator:
source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:16:25: warning: C++20 says that these are ambiguous, even though the second is reversed:
   16 |     std::cout << (a1 == a2) << std::endl;
      |                         ^~
<source>:5:17: note: candidate 1: 'bool operator==(const PartialEq<A>&, const A&)'
    5 |     friend bool operator==(PartialEq const&, Type const&) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
<source>:5:17: note: candidate 2: 'bool operator==(const PartialEq<A>&, const A&)' (reversed)

Program returned: 0

I understand the problem but I can't find a solution for now.
Any ideas?
I searched for a way to fix it and found this topic: Ambiguous Overloaded Operator C++20, but the situation is a bit different from mine because of my usage of CRTP.

I understand the problem...  What is your understanding of the problem?  I understand the problem too, and the solution I'd use is straightforward friend bool operator==(Type const&, Type const&) or friend bool operator==(PartialEq const&, PartialEq const&).  I don't understand why the straightforward solution is not an option.
